# Export to CSV in Oracle SQL Developer not quoting values

Tags: oracle, csv, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to export the results of a query in Oracle SQL Developer. One of my columns is a user-defined type which looks like this when it gets exported:

```
SDE.ST_GEOMETRY(1,1,2702721.09480406,249404.580511138,2702721.09480406,249404.580511138,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,0,2272,'oracle.sql.BLOB@615bd3ac')
```

The problem is that SQL Developer doesn't quote values of this column, even though I've specified left and right enclosures of `"`, and the commas inside the parentheses break my CSV file.

Is there any way to force SQL Developer to enclose *all* values on export?

Comment: those are numbers, that's why they're not being quoted

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I guess I was expecting the entire string to have double quotes around it. It's fine that the numbers aren't quoted, but the raw commas in between them are breaking my CSV output. This is just one column and the interior commas makes it look like multiple columns to other applications.

Comment: w/o your code I can't really say what's going on then...but i would fix this with the query itself, add the quotes to your query, select " || col || " ...

Comment: @thatjeffsmith unfortunately I can't share the code for the data type, as it's part of a commercial software package (Esri ArcGIS). I can fix this with the query, but I still feel like any column that evaluates to a string should be quoted, no? In any case, thanks for taking a look at this!

Comment: I would agree in general...I just need a test case to reproduce and log the issue if necessary. FWIW, my wife uses that software, maybe I'll go ping her :) You can open a support request with My Oracle Support if you have a database support contract.

Comment: Jura: I'm just speculating here, but I suppose you don't get the double-quote escapes because the data type of your column is **not** text. You said it's a user-defined type. I suppose SQL Developer doesn't have the ability to let you specify which data types (including user defined ones) to be enclosed in double-quotes. I would **not** try to add double-quotes by hand in your code; rather, convert (if possible) your values to varchar2, then SQL Developer should automatically add the double-quotes. In any case, if you don't know, you are in good hands with thatjeff, he's the boss of SQL Dev!

Answer (score 0):

As seen from your problem add extra pipes in beginning and end of the column as like:

```
select ||'|'||column1||'|'|| from table1;
```